# How to solve a TabLayout inside a Fragment which includes four Tabs created by one Fragment with newInstance() using RecyclerView

Tags: fragment, android-recyclerview, multiple-instances, android-tablayout

I implement an Activity which contains a `NavigationView` with includes several fragments. The first Fragment of the `NavigationView` contains a `RecyclerView` with a `TabLayout`, so that I can swipe between the different lists. Because I've got always the same list(UI) with different values, I decided to implement only one Fragment with a `newInstance()`.

My problem now is that the list does not update properly when I jump from Tab1 to Tab2 or if I change a list item and come back to the list. Can somebody help me? I can't figure it out ...

[swipe from Tab1 to Tab2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BQoT.png)
This is my fragment which contains the `RecyclerView`:

```html
public class HinweiseFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "HinweiseFragment";
    private TabLayout mTabLayout;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private HinweiseTabAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Hinweise");

        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).showFloatingActionButton();

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_hinweise, null);

        mTabLayout = (TabLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tablayout_hinweise);
        mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setText("BESAMUNG"));
        mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setText("NICHT BESAMEN"));
        mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setText("VERDACHT"));
        mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setText("ALLE"));
        mTabLayout.setTabGravity(mTabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager_hinweise);
        adapter = new HinweiseTabAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), mTabLayout.getTabCount(), getContext());

        mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);


        mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(mTabLayout));
        mTabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition(), true);
                adapter.refreshFragment(tab.getPosition());

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            }
        });

        return rootView;

    }
}
```

This is my TabAdapter:

```html
public class HinweiseTabAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    HinweiseListFragment tab_besamung, tab_nicht, tab_verdacht, tab_alle;
    String[] tabHostTitle = {"BESAMUNG", "NICHT BESAMEN", "VERDACHT", "ALLE"};
    int mNumOfTabs;
    private final Context mContext;

    public HinweiseTabAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs, Context context) {
        super(fm);
        this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                tab_besamung = HinweiseListFragment.newInstance(0, "BESAMUNG");
                return tab_besamung;
            case 1:
                tab_nicht = HinweiseListFragment.newInstance(1, "NICHT BESAMEN");
                return tab_nicht;
            case 2:
                tab_verdacht = HinweiseListFragment.newInstance(2, "VERDACHT");
                return tab_verdacht;
            case 3:
                tab_alle = HinweiseListFragment.newInstance(3, "ALLE");
                return tab_alle;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    public void refreshFragment(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                tab_besamung.update();
                break;
            case 1:
                tab_nicht.update();
                break;
            case 2:
                tab_verdacht.update();
                break;
            case 3:
                tab_alle.update();
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        int position = getItemPosition(object);

        if (position >= 0) {
            return position;
        } else {
            return POSITION_NONE;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNumOfTabs;

    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabHostTitle[position];
    }
}
```

and this is my Fragment which contains the List:

```html
    public static HinweiseListFragment newInstance(int page, String title) {
        HinweiseListFragment fragment = new HinweiseListFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(PASSED_PAGE, page);
        args.putString(PASSED_TITLE, title);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        if (args != null) {
            tabCount = args.getInt(PASSED_PAGE);
            tabName = args.getString(PASSED_TITLE);
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_hinweise_list, container, false);

        list_hinweise = new ArrayList<>();

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rv_listHinweise);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.swipeHinweise);

        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                        refreshContent();
                    }
                });

            }
        });

        db = new DataBase(getActivity());
        userHitKdr();

        List<String> tab_ = db.getAll("SELECT * from tab_info where user_tab ='" + userdb + "' ");
        if (tab_.size() != 2) {
            db.updateSql("delete from tab_info where user_tab='" + userdb + "' ");
            db.updateSql("insert into tab_info (activity_tab,tab_select,user_tab) values ('home','0','" + userdb + "'),('aufgabe','0','" + userdb + "'); ");
        } else {
        }

        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        mHinweiseAdapter = new HinweiseAdapter(getActivity(), getHinweise());
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mHinweiseAdapter);

        ItemClickSupport.addTo(mRecyclerView).setOnItemClickListener(new ItemClickSupport.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClicked(RecyclerView recyclerView, int position, View v) {
                Intent detailView = new Intent(getActivity(), HinweiseDetail.class);

                String[] tierarr = new String[tier_id.size()];
                tier_id.toArray(tierarr);
                String[] hinarr = new String[hin_id.size()];
                hin_id.toArray(hinarr);
                detailView.putExtra("detailart", "ovalert");
                detailView.putExtra("idTier", tier_id.get(position));
                detailView.putExtra("idDetail", hin_id.get(position));
                int ipos = position;
                Integer integerConverter = new Integer(ipos);
                String s = integerConverter.toString();
                detailView.putExtra("pos", s);
                detailView.putExtra("arrIdTier", tierarr);
                detailView.putExtra("arrIdHin", hinarr);

                detailView.putExtra("userDetail", userdb);
                detailView.putExtra("hitDetail", hitdb);
                startActivity(detailView);
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }


    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

        if (isVisibleToUser) {
            if(list_hinweise != null) {
                update();
            }
        }
    }

    public String checkTab(int tab) {
        tabCount = tab;
        //tabName = name;

        if (tabCount == 0) {
            auswahl = " animalReproductionIndication.off='0' and (animalReproductionIndication.indicationCertainty ='IN'  or animalReproductionIndication.indicationCertainty ='ID' or animalReproductionIndication.indicationCertainty ='' ) and ";
            db.updateSql("update tab_info set tab_select='" + tabCount + "' where activity_tab='home' and  user_tab='" + userdb + "' ");

            if (list_hinweise != null) {
                list_hinweise.clear();
                if (mHinweiseAdapter != null) {
                    mHinweiseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        if (tabCount == 1) {
            auswahl = " animalReproductionIndication.off='0' and  (animalReproductionIndication.indicationCertainty ='NI'  or animalReproductionIndication.indicationCertainty ='HO') and ";
            db.updateSql("update tab_info set tab_select='" + tabCount + "' where activity_tab='home' and  user_tab='" + userdb + "' ");

            if (list_hinweise != null) {
                list_hinweise.clear();
                if (mHinweiseAdapter != null) {
                    mHinweiseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        if (tabCount == 2) {
            auswahl = " animalReproductionIndication.off='0' and  animalReproductionIndication.indicationCertainty ='SU' and ";
            db.updateSql("update tab_info set tab_select='" + tabCount + "' where activity_tab='home' and  user_tab='" + userdb + "' ");

            if (list_hinweise != null) {
                list_hinweise.clear();
                if (mHinweiseAdapter != null) {
                    mHinweiseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        }
        if (tabCount == 3) {
            auswahl = " animalReproductionIndication.off='0' and  (animalReproductionIndication.indicationCertainty ='IN' or animalReproductionIndication.indicationCertainty ='NI' or animalReproductionIndication.indicationCertainty ='SU' or animalReproductionIndication.indicationCertainty ='ID'  or animalReproductionIndication.indicationCertainty ='HO') and ";
            db.updateSql("update tab_info set tab_select='" + tabCount + "' where activity_tab='home' and  user_tab='" + userdb + "' ");

            if (list_hinweise != null) {
                list_hinweise.clear();
                if (mHinweiseAdapter != null) {
                    mHinweiseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        return auswahl;
    }

    public void update(){
        tabCount = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt(PASSED_PAGE) : 0;
        tabName = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getString(PASSED_TITLE) : "BESAMUNG";
        list_hinweise.clear();
        mHinweiseAdapter = new HinweiseAdapter(getActivity(), getHinweise());
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mHinweiseAdapter);
    }

    public void refreshContent() {
        importIndication();

        tabCount = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt(PASSED_PAGE) : 0;
        tabName = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getString(PASSED_TITLE) : "BESAMUNG";
        list_hinweise.clear();
        mHinweiseAdapter = new HinweiseAdapter(getActivity(), getHinweise());
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mHinweiseAdapter);
        // stopping swipe refresh
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    }


    private List<ListHinweise> getHinweise() {
        checkTab(tabCount);

        tm = new DateTime();
        rg = new DateRegex();
        tt = new DateTime();

        try {
            db.checkAndCopyDatabase();
            db.openDatabase();
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String sqlSortName = "select nameCode from sortieren where art='1' and (disable='0' or disable='1') and user='" + userdb + "'  group by nameCode ";
        String sqlSortDisable = "select disable from sortieren where art='1' and (disable='0' or disable='1') and user='" + userdb + "'  group by nameCode ";

        List<String> listSortName = db.getAll(sqlSortName);
        List<String> listSortDisable = db.getAll(sqlSortDisable);

        String sortSql = "";
        for (int s1 = 0; s1 < listSortName.size(); s1++) {
            System.out.println("Sort: " + listSortDisable.get(s1));
            if (s1 == listSortName.size() - 1) {
                String orderby = " desc ";
                if (listSortDisable.get(s1).equals("0"))
                    orderby = " asc ";
                if (listSortName.get(s1).equals("indicationDateTime"))
                    sortSql = sortSql + " animalReproductionIndication." + listSortName.get(s1) + " " + orderby;
                else if (listSortName.get(s1).equals("farmersAnimalNr"))
                    sortSql = sortSql + " cast(OVALERTAPP." + listSortName.get(s1) + " as integer) " + orderby;
                else
                    sortSql = sortSql + " OVALERTAPP." + listSortName.get(s1) + " " + orderby;
            } else {
                String orderby = " desc ,";
                if (listSortDisable.get(s1).equals("0"))
                    orderby = " asc ,";
                if (listSortName.get(s1).equals("indicationDateTime"))
                    sortSql = sortSql + " animalReproductionIndication." + listSortName.get(s1) + " " + orderby;
                else if (listSortName.get(s1).equals("farmersAnimalNr"))
                    sortSql = sortSql + " cast(OVALERTAPP." + listSortName.get(s1) + " as integer) " + orderby;
                else
                    sortSql = sortSql + " OVALERTAPP." + listSortName.get(s1) + " " + orderby;
            }
        }
        String sxc = sortSql;
        sxc = sxc.trim();
        if (!sxc.equals(""))
            sortSql = " order by " + sortSql;

        System.out.println("Sort: " + sortSql);

        try {
            sql = " FROM OVALERTAPP, animalReproductionIndication WHERE " + sql_user_hit + " OVALERTAPP.AnimalNumber= animalReproductionIndication.AnimalNumber and " + auswahl + "1 " + sortSql;
            String prio = db.getSelect("select nameCode from primaeridentifikation where  user='" + userdb + "' and art='1' and disable='1'  ");

            List<String> einstellung_name = db.getAll("SELECT name from einstellungen where user ='" + userdb + "' and seite='1' and disable='1' ");
            List<String> einstellung_nameCode = db.getAll("SELECT nameCode from  einstellungen where user ='" + userdb + "' and seite='1' and disable='1' ");
            String xxInhalt = " ";
            for (int xx = 0; xx < einstellung_name.size(); xx++) {
                String namexx = einstellung_name.get(xx);
                for (int yy = 0; yy < namexx_.length; yy++) {
                    namexx = namexx.replace(namexx_[yy], Abkxx_[yy]);
                }
                xxInhalt = xxInhalt + "' " + namexx + ": ' ||  OVALERTAPP." + einstellung_nameCode.get(xx) + "    ||";
            }
            xxInhalt = " || '<br>' || " + xxInhalt + " ''";
            xxInhalt = xxInhalt.replace("OVALERTAPP.participantAnimal", "OVALERTAPP.participantAnimalNr");
            if (einstellung_name.size() < 1) {
                xxInhalt = " ";
            }

            tier_id = db.getAll("SELECT OVALERTAPP.id " + sql);
            hin_id = db.getAll("SELECT animalReproductionIndication.id " + sql);
            hin_besamt = db.getAll("SELECT animalReproductionIndication.indicationCertainty " + sql);
            hin_blaue = db.getAll("select animalReproductionIndication.showType " + sql);
            hin_time = db.getAll("select animalReproductionIndication.indicationDateTime " + sql); //gesehen

            if (prio.equals("")) {
                String sql_ = " SELECT  OVALERTAPP.AnimalNumber ||  ' I.H: ' ||  '--'    || ' T I.B: ' || OVALERTAPP.lastInseminationDate    || ' T LT: '  || OVALERTAPP.calvingDate  || '  T  '||  reproductionStatus " + xxInhalt + " " + sql; // time
                sql_ = sql_.replace("OVALERTAPP.aktivseit", "animalReproductionIndication.indicationDateTime");
                hin_info = db.getAll(sql_);
                // hin_info = db.getAll(" SELECT  OVALERTAPP.AnimalNumber ||  ' I.H: ' ||  '--'    || ' T I.B: ' || OVALERTAPP.lastInseminationDate    || ' T LT: '  || OVALERTAPP.calvingDate  || '  T  '||  reproductionStatus " + xxInhalt + " " + sql); // time

                System.out.println(" SELECT  OVALERTAPP.AnimalNumber ||  ' I.H: ' ||  '--'    || ' T I.B: ' || OVALERTAPP.lastInseminationDate    || ' T LT: '  || OVALERTAPP.calvingDate  || '  T  '||  reproductionStatus " + xxInhalt + " " + sql); // time

            } else {
                //hin_info = db.getAll(" SELECT   OVALERTAPP." + prio + " ||  ' I.H: ' ||  '--'    || ' T I.B: ' || OVALERTAPP.lastInseminationDate    || ' T LT: '  || OVALERTAPP.calvingDate  || '  T  '||  reproductionStatus " + xxInhalt + " " + sql); // time
                String sql_ = " SELECT   OVALERTAPP." + prio + " ||  ' I.H: ' ||  '--'    || ' T I.B: ' || OVALERTAPP.lastInseminationDate    || ' T LT: '  || OVALERTAPP.calvingDate  || '  T  '||  reproductionStatus " + xxInhalt + " " + sql; // time

                sql_ = sql_.replace("OVALERTAPP.aktivseit", "animalReproductionIndication.indicationDateTime");
                hin_info = db.getAll(sql_);
                System.out.println(" SELECT   OVALERTAPP." + prio + " ||  ' I.H: ' ||  '--'    || ' T I.B: ' || OVALERTAPP.lastInseminationDate    || ' T LT: '  || OVALERTAPP.calvingDate  || '  T  '||  reproductionStatus " + xxInhalt + " " + sql); // time


            }

            for (int i = 0; i < hin_besamt.size(); i++) {

                String timehin = db.getSelect("SELECT   indicationDateTime  FROM   animalReproductionIndication  where animalReproductionIndication.id=" + hin_id.get(i));
                String animalhin = db.getSelect("SELECT   animalNumber  FROM   animalReproductionIndication  where animalReproductionIndication.id=" + hin_id.get(i));
                // List<String> maxList=db.getAll("SELECT  indicationDateTime FROM   animalReproductionIndication  where  user='"+userdb+"' and  animalNumber='"+animalhin+"'  and indicationDateTime!='"+timehin+"' and indicationExpirationDateTime !=''   order by indicationDateTime desc  ");
                String timehin_date = timehin + "         ";
                List<String> maxList = db.getAll("SELECT  indicationDateTimeHin FROM   animalReproductionIndicationHinweise  where  userHin='" + userdb + "' and  animalNumberHin='" + animalhin + "'  and indicationDateTimeHin!='" + timehin + "' and (indicationDateTimeHin  not LIKE '" + timehin_date.substring(0, 8) + "%') and indicationDateTimeHin < '" + timehin + "'  order by indicationDateTimeHin desc  ");

                String hin = "";
                if (maxList.size() > 0) {
                    hin = maxList.get(0);
                    System.out.println("hin++++" + hin + " neue: " + timehin);
                }
                //hin=tm.getDayToDay(hin,"yyyyMMddkkmmss");
                hin = tm.getDayMinusDayDate(hin, timehin);
                String line = statusUmbenennen(hin_info.get(i));
                System.out.println("line: " + line);
                String info_ = statusUmbenennen(hin_info.get(i));
                System.out.println("line1: " + line);
                info_ = info_.replace("--", hin);
                System.out.println("line2: " + info_);
                System.out.println(info_);
                String[] anfang = {"I Kalb: ", "I Bes: ", "n Kalb: ", "I Bru: ", " Trocken: "};
                String[] end = {"", "", "", "", ""};


                String[] anfang1 = {"I.H: ", "I.B: ", "LT: "};
                String[] end1 = {"", "", ""};
                try {
                    info_ = lineYMDTag(info_, anfang1, end1);
                    System.out.println("line3: " + info_);

                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                String[] anfangx = {"Aktiv seit: "};
                String[] endx = {""};
                try {
                    info_ = lineYMDHMS(info_, anfangx, endx);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    info_ = lineYMD(info_, anfang, end);
                    System.out.println("line4: " + info_);

                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                System.out.println("info_: " + info_);
                ListHinweise item = new ListHinweise();
                item.setHinId(tier_id.get(i));
                item.setHinId(hin_id.get(i));
                item.setHinBlaue(hin_blaue.get(i));
                item.setHinInfo(info_);
                item.setHinBesamt(hin_besamt.get(i));
                System.out.println(hin_time.get(i) + "_xmmx_" + tt.getHourDiffStartToNow(hin_time.get(i), "yyyyMMddkkmmss"));
                item.setHinTime(String.valueOf(tt.getHourDiffStartToNow(hin_time.get(i), "yyyyMMddkkmmss")));
                list_hinweise.add(item);

                db.close();
            }

        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return list_hinweise;
    }
```

I have already tried to update the list with onResume or setUserVisibleHint but without success. My refreshContent() method works fine, but I want to update the list automatically and not manually. If I took the onResume() method the Items will be refreshed but then my Tab1 contains the values from Tab1 and Tab2.

Comment: If I start the app ...  every tab gots the same value of tab1 ... I can see it if i swipe through the tabs, but if I click on the tab everything works fine ... only if I swipe I can see the values of Tab1 and if the selected Tab is open my fragment will be refreshed by adapter in method: refreshFragment()

Comment: my problem is the effect by swiping through the tabs because I can see the values of TAB1 (see uploaded picture)

Comment: I solved this Problem by using AsyncTasks for each fragment and boolean operators in userVisibleHint() method. First boolean operator checks "first start" in onCreateView and second boolean checks if view is visible in userVisibleHint ... :)